# update list with new column

Tags: 2013, list

In my feature activation i create list. But now i want to add new column to list withouth deleting list and recreating new one. This is my existing code to create list

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteRoot.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                try
                {

                    SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
                    SPList listexist = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                    if (listexist == null)
                    {

                        lists.Add(listName, "List to upload emp info", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);

                        SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
                        list.AnonymousPermMask64 = SPBasePermissions.EditListItems;

                        SPField deptField = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");
                        deptField.Title = "Contact Name";
                        deptField.PushChangesToLists = true;   // *** push to list
                        deptField.Update(true);            // *** using Update(true) updates list & DB
                        list.Update();


                        // create Text type new column called "My Column" 
                        //list.Fields.Add("Name", SPFieldType.Text, true);
                        list.Fields.Add("Email", SPFieldType.Text, true);
                        list.Fields.Add("Manager", SPFieldType.Note, true);

                        //Winnerstatus to show all the winners
                        list.Fields.Add("Winnerstatus", SPFieldType.Boolean, false);


                        // make new column visible in default view
                        SPView view = list.DefaultView;
                        view.ViewFields.Add("Email");
                        view.ViewFields.Add("Name");
                        view.ViewFields.Add("Manager");

                        view.Update();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

There is something called `list.Fields.ContainsField("NewColumn")` to check if column exist or not. But what is better way to fit in this code. Because first i have this condition below

```
if listexist == null
```

so does it mean i have to add one more condition to check if listexist != null and then do check for column exist or not? Is there better way?

Answer (score 0):

Just try it like this:

```
SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
SPList listexist = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
if (listexist == null){
  //do your stuff
}
else{
  //check if list already has this field, if not, add it.
  if(!listexist.Fields.ContainsField("NewColumn")){
        //add the column to your list
  }
}
```

Comment: Where i get list variable?

Comment: sorry corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static bool Field_ISAlreadyExists(List newList, string Field_InternalName, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        FieldCollection collFields = newList.Fields;
        clientContext.Load(collFields);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // Check existing fields
        bool _IsAlreadyExists = false;

        if (Field_InternalName != "")
        {
            var fieldExists = collFields.Any(f => f.InternalName.Trim().ToLower() == Field_InternalName.Trim().ToLower());

            if (fieldExists)
            {
                _IsAlreadyExists = true;
                //Console.WriteLine("This Column " + Field_InternalName + " is already exist");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _IsAlreadyExists = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter correct list column detail.");
        }

        return _IsAlreadyExists;
    }
```

OR

```
    private static bool ContainsField(List list, string fieldName)
    {
        var ctx = list.Context;
        var result = ctx.LoadQuery(list.Fields.Where(f => f.InternalName == fieldName));
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        return result.Any();
    }
```

> These two functions may help you. Here I am using CSOM approach.

Comment: where do you check if list exist or not?